# Double Arrow Error in Html Link Cake Php

Tags: php, html, cakephp, hyperlink

I keep on getting this double arrow error.
"Error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
File: C:\wamp\www\reminders_cakephp\app\View\Reminders\index.ctp
Line: 22". I am using CakePhp Framework and I am very certain that using double arrow is necessary and correct. However, I don't know why I'm getting this error.
here is the code:

```
<?php 
                echo $this->Html->link(
                    $reminder['Reminder']['reminderDesc'],
                    $array(
                        'controller' => 'reminders',
                        'action' => 'view',
                         $reminder['Reminder']['reminderId']
                    )
                ); 
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably one dollar sign too much here: `$array`

Comment: @Rizier123 it damned worked! Thank you so much. I realized I must not only focused on the printed error but also look on other things. That dollar sign. Thank you again!